# Experience Editor editing not working empty edit fields

Tags: experience-editor

I've some problems in the experience editor. As you can see in the screenshot I can edit the picture and headline, but the text I can't directly edit. Only the small empty field and when I click in there I can insert some text and the real text is gone and the new text shows up. It looks like that the HTML edit from sitecore is not focusing the right field, but I am using the HTMLString to render the fields.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the HTML Code for this component

[image]

when I remove the p tag around the Text its working again